# How to get the input answer, and then put it on a html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how to save the link that the user put and then put it on the image tag.

 
**IMPORTANT**: I'm using jquery by the way

[Here is how my code looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwNoI.png)

Also you can see it down here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Superhero Cards Maker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id="h2">Superhero Cards Maker</h2>
    <div class="input">
      <label>Put the link of your image </label>
      <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/i-am-iron-man-avengers-endgame-5k-4r-1280x720.jpg"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="options">
      <button class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
      <button id="add-card">Add Card</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cards-template">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardbook"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(".cards-template").hide();
    function addCard() {
      var noteHtml = $(".cards-template").html();
      $(".cardbook").prepend(noteHtml);
      let image =$('.input')
      console.log(image)
      $(".card").append('<h3 class="title" contenteditable="true">Type the name of your hero here (delete this)</h3><p class="content" contenteditable="true">Type the description here (delete this)</p><img src="">')
    }
    $("#add-card").click(addCard);
  </script>
</html>
```

What I want to do:
So imagine you are a user that wants to create a superhero card, you have a title, content and your image, there is a input field that let you put your image link adress, then the website will save that link put it on the src of the html image tag, and create your card with the heading and the paragraph of course.

What I try:
I try to save the content of my input field into a variable and then just show it into the console to see if I can see the link that the user put, but it says null

```html
<script>
    $(".cards-template").hide();
    function addCard() {
      var noteHtml = $(".cards-template").html();
      $(".cardbook").prepend(noteHtml);
      let image =$('.input')
      console.log(image)
      $(".card").append('<h3 class="title" contenteditable="true">Type the name of your hero here (delete this)</h3><p class="content" contenteditable="true">Type the description here (delete this)</p><img src="">')
    }
    $("#add-card").click(addCard);
  </script>
```

Comment: `<img src="">` I see this in the line where you're appending HTML into `.card`. You already have access `.input` element, so why not replace `<img src="">` with `<img src="' + image.val() + '">`?

Comment: And also, I see you have `id="input"`, in that case you should be selecting it with `$("#input")` not `$(".input")`. This is why you see `null`.

Comment: You can hard code the img tag and with jquery or vanilla js update the src or the url you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the value with `val()` method you can select image with jQuery selector and after that you can set `src` attribute and img tag with `attr()` method. I've added an `id` attribute of `input` to the input field so that it can be selected using the `#input` selector.

Here is a snippet. Hope it helps.

```js
function addCard() {
      var noteHtml = $(".cards-template").html();
      $(".cardbook").prepend(noteHtml);
      
      // get the value of the input field
      var imageUrl = $("#input").val();
    
      // select the img tag and set its src attribute
      $(".card img").attr("src", imageUrl);
    
      // append the heading and paragraph tags
      $(".card").append('<h3 class="title" contenteditable="true">Type the name of your hero here (delete this)</h3><p class="content" contenteditable="true">Type the description here (delete this)</p>');
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much it works, but when I add the first card it doesnt show me the image until I add a second card, so lets say I can only see the images if I put 2 cards on the website, and also when I try to put another image, it change all the images of my cards

But it kinda work your code so thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. You can use jQuery's eq() method to select only the img tag within the current .card. The problem is that you're using the .card img selector, which selects all img tags within the .card element.